# Ignoring EventViewer for ListViewItem when the overlayed button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a program where I'm creating a ListView with a series of ListViewItems I add programmatically. I'm also overlaying a button that allows you to remove that item from the ListView. However, when I click on it, it activates the EventSetter that I have added for the entire ListView, which I want to be ignored when this button is clicked.

Is there a way to make it such that when you click on that button, only that event fires and not the one for the ListViewItem? I've tried setting `e.Handled=true` in the function for the button click but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="SavedClipboardList"  
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Width="600"
    Height="460"
    Background="#282828"
    BorderThickness="0"
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
    VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20, 0, 20, 5" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="SavedClipboardList_ItemClick"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="525">
                    <Image Source= "/Assets/Placeholder.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBlock Text= "{Binding body}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#ffffff"/>
                </StackPanel>
                
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="Auto">
                    <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Foreground="#FFFFFF" Click="btnRemove_Click">X</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` is a tunneling event that gets raised *before* the `Click` event for the `Button`.

> Is there a way to make it such that when you click on that button, only that event fires and not the one for the ListViewItem?

If you don't want to handle the tunneling event when the `Button` is clicked, you could check whether the `OriginalSource` of the `MouseButtonEventArgs` that gets passed to the `SavedClipboardList_ItemClick` event handler is part of a `Button`:

```
private void SavedClipboardList_ItemClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is Button || (e.OriginalSource is DependencyObject dependencyObject
        && FindParent<Button>(dependencyObject) != null))
        return;

    // handle item click just like before...
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);
    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}

private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // handle button click...
}
```

You cannot prevent the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event from being raised though.

Comment: That works a treat, thanks so much! Just for some clarification, what is GetParent(dependencyObject) doing here? identifying if it's a button or not? Thanks again!

Comment: `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` gets the parent element of the `dependencyObject` in the visual tree. `FindParent<T>` recursively gets the parent element of type `T` of `dependencyObject`.